# Scatterpie plot with patterns

Tags: r, scatterpie, ggpattern

I'm using the `R` `scatterpie` package for plotting pie charts on an xy plane. Each one of the pies/groups also has a `class` assignment which I would also like to convey in the plot and was thinking of using patterns for that.

Here's the example `data.frame`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)
library(scatterpie)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(50, 0, 100), y = runif(50, 0, 100), id = paste0("id",1:50),
                 g1 = as.integer(runif(50, 0, 100)), g2 = as.integer(runif(50, 0, 100)), g3 = as.integer(runif(50, 0, 100)),
                 class = sample(c("c1", "c2"), 50, replace = T)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(size = 0.02*(g1 + g2 + g3))
df$class <- factor(df$class)
```

Here's the code I tried with the `ggpattern` package:

```
ggplot() + geom_scatterpie(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, group = id, r = size),cols = paste0("g",1:3),color = "black", alpha = 0.8, size = 0.1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#FFC9F8", "#ee9e77", "#895A44")) +
  geom_col_pattern(aes(pattern_fill = class))+
  xlim(-10,110) + ylim(-10,110) + coord_equal() + theme_void()
```

Which gives the error:

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in `f()`:
! Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): pattern_fill = class. 
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?
```

I tried playing around with the `pattern` part of the command but with no success.

Currently, the only way I am able to encode the `class` of each pie is with the `linetype` aesthetics argument:

```
ggplot() + geom_scatterpie(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, group = id, r = size, linetype = class),cols = paste0("g",1:3), color = "black", size = 1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#FFC9F8", "#ee9e77", "#895A44")) +
  xlim(-10,110) + ylim(-10,110) + coord_equal() + theme_void()
```

[image]

But it's not ideal.

Any idea how to make this work or alternative ways to encode `class`?

Comment: I think it is unlikely you'll be able to make those two packages work together. You'd need a `geom_scatterpie_pattern`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Right. Any suggestion on alternative ways of how to convey the `class` of each pie?

Comment: You could make the three classes different colors, then map `type` to the alpha channel to get three shades of each color.

Comment: I sort of understand what you're saying but don't know how to implement the `map type to the alpha channel` part of your comment. Can I ask you to write it down?

Comment: Ok looking at `geom_scatterpie` in more detail, it violates all the design principles of ggplot, so my idea doesn't really work, sorry.

Comment: Some thoughts, and while it generates an image (and does not error), I don't think it's what you're going for. (1) Because you're only passing data to `geom_scatterpie`, the NSE of `pattern_fill=class` does not have `df` to find its column named `class`, but if finds instead the primitive function `class(.)`, which is obviously wrong. Add `df` to `ggplot(df)`. (2) `geom_col_pattern` also needs `x=` and `y=`, also only provided to `geom_scatterpie`, I suggest `ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))`. Unfortunately scatterpie still needs them as well, back to Axeman's comment about violations.

Comment: And **subjectively** ... I find your suggested plot above to be _really difficult to interpret_ as a whole. The add dimension within each pie makes it nearly impossible to do a "mile stare" and see the whole relationship, all I can really see without looking at each pie is x, y, and radius; that might be enough, at which point if the plot is as much for lookup, then the user can then drill down to look at one or two pies ... but even then, it's nearly impossible to do comparison between two (or more!) pies, so it is inching towards "too much data, just for fun", drowning the viewer.

Comment: @r2evans I agree completely. The visualization is possible (see below), but is difficult to interpret.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not convinced about the visualization, though it is possible via ggplot and ggpattern. I don't think you can use `geom_scatterpie`, which, as Axeman points out, doesn't really work the way other ggplot geoms do.

If I *had* to do this, I would probably just make my own pie function and draw the result with `geom_polygon_pattern`.

You could do that with the following helper function:

```r
make_pie <- function(x, y, size, groups, n, class, rownum) {
  angles <- c(0, 2*pi * cumsum(n)/sum(n))
  do.call("rbind", Map(function(a1, a2, g) {
    xvals <- c(0, sin(seq(a1, a2, len = 30)) * size, 0) + x
    yvals <- c(0, cos(seq(a1, a2, len = 30)) * size, 0) + y
    data.frame(x = xvals, y = yvals, group = g, class = class, rownum = rownum)
  }, head(angles, -1), tail(angles, -1), groups))
}
```

You can then plot using your data as follows:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(r = row_number()) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  group_map(~ with(.x, make_pie(x, y, size, c("g1", "g2", "g3"),
                                c(g1, g2, g3), class, r))) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = group, group = interaction(group, rownum))) +
  geom_polygon_pattern(aes(pattern = class), pattern_fill = "black",
                       pattern_angle = 45, pattern_spacing = 0.01,
                       pattern_density = 0.1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FFC9F8", "#ee9e77", "#895A44")) +
  guides(pattern = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "white"))) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

You could map the alpha channel as Axeman suggests like this:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(r = row_number()) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  group_map(~ with(.x, make_pie(x, y, size, c("g1", "g2", "g3"),
                                c(g1, g2, g3), class, r))) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = class, group = interaction(group, rownum),
             alpha = group)) +
  geom_polygon() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red4", "green4")) +
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.3, 0.7, 1)) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Or just declare each fill color individually:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(r = row_number()) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  group_map(~ with(.x, make_pie(x, y, size, c("g1", "g2", "g3"),
                                c(g1, g2, g3), class, r))) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  mutate(fill_class = paste0(group, " (class ", class, ")")) %>%
  mutate(fill_class = factor(fill_class, unique(fill_class))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = fill_class, group = interaction(group, rownum))) +
  geom_polygon() +
  scale_fill_manual("Group (class)",
                    values = c("red3", "hotpink", "red", 
                               "navy", "blue", "dodgerblue")) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for making this work; +1 for coming up with a replacement for `geom_scatterpie` (though it can and should be fixed); and +1 for the last plot that is a vast improvement on the use of patterns. Bravo!

Comment: Great solution. I wouldn't worry too much about the interpretability of this example dataset.

Comment: Well done! The colored variants are a nice improvement over the patterns.

Comment: @Allan Cameron, I'm wondering if you can take a look at a followup post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77413533/r-scatter-pie-plots-with-pattern-in-slices