# R scatter pie plots with pattern in slices

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, scatterpie, ggpattern

This is a followup question to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77002690/scatterpie-plot-with-patterns).

I have an `R` `data.frame` where each row describes a composition that I want to plot as a pie on an xy plane. I want to color-code the slices of each pie by their `y.a_1`, `y.a_2`, `y.a_3`, `y.a_4`, `y.b_1`, `y.b_2`, `y.b_3`, `y.b_4`, `o.a_1`, `o.a_3`, `o.a_4`, `o.b_1`, `o.b_3`, `o.b_4`, in the example `df` below. The `class` column used in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77002690/scatterpie-plot-with-patterns) is not included in `df` at this point because it is not a pie-specific property but rather a property of the slices, and is created below.

Here's the `df`:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = runif(10, 0, 100), y = runif(10, 0, 100), id = paste0("id",1:10),
                 y.a_1 = as.integer(runif(10, 0, 100)), y.a_2 = as.integer(runif(10, 0, 100)), y.a_3 = as.integer(runif(10, 0, 100)), y.a_4 = as.integer(runif(10, 0, 100)),
                 y.b_1 = as.integer(runif(10, 0, 100)), y.b_2 = as.integer(runif(10, 0, 100)), y.b_3 = as.integer(runif(10, 0, 100)), y.b_4 = as.integer(runif(10, 0, 100)),
                 o.a_1 = as.integer(runif(10, 0, 100)), o.a_3 = as.integer(runif(10, 0, 100)), o.a_4 = as.integer(runif(10, 0, 100)),
                 o.b_1 = as.integer(runif(10, 0, 100)), o.b_3 = as.integer(runif(10, 0, 100)), o.b_4 = as.integer(runif(10, 0, 100))) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(size = runif(10,0.002,0.01)*(y.a_1 + y.a_2 + y.a_3 + y.a_4 + y.b_1 + y.b_2 + y.b_3 + y.b_4 + o.a_1 + o.a_3 + o.a_4 + o.b_1 + o.b_3 + o.b_4))
```

Following [Allan Cameron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12500315/allan-cameron)'s solution I define this function for creating pie polygons:

```
make_pie <- function(x, y, size, groups, n, rownum) {
  angles <- c(0, 2*pi * cumsum(n)/sum(n))
  do.call("rbind", Map(function(a1, a2, g) {
    xvals <- c(0, sin(seq(a1, a2, len = 30)) * size, 0) + x
    yvals <- c(0, cos(seq(a1, a2, len = 30)) * size, 0) + y
    data.frame(x = xvals, y = yvals, group = g, rownum = rownum)
  }, head(angles, -1), tail(angles, -1), groups))
}
```

Again, `class` is not included in this function because it was not part of `df`.

However, I add a `class` column to the `data.frame` created by running `df` through the `make_pie` function:

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(r = row_number()) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  group_map(~ with(.x, make_pie(x, y,
                                size, c("y.a_1", "y.a_2", "y.a_3", "y.a_4", "y.b_1", "y.b_2", "y.b_3", "y.b_4", "o.a_1", "o.a_3", "o.a_4", "o.b_1", "o.b_3", "o.b_4"),
                                c(y.a_1, y.a_2, y.a_3, y.a_4, y.b_1, y.b_2, y.b_3, y.b_4, o.a_1, o.a_3, o.a_4, o.b_1, o.b_3, o.b_4), r))) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  mutate(class = gsub("\\.a","",group) %>% gsub("\\.b","",.)) %>% unique()
df$group <- factor(df$group, levels = c("y.a_1", "y.a_2", "y.a_3", "y.a_4", "y.b_1", "y.b_2", "y.b_3", "y.b_4", "o.a_1", "o.a_3", "o.a_4", "o.b_1", "o.b_3", "o.b_4"))
df$class <- factor(df$class, levels = c("y_1", "y_2", "y_3", "y_4", "o_1", "o_3", "o_4"))
```

Then I use this `ggplot2` and `ggpattern` function:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpattern)

ggplot(df,aes(x, y, fill = group, group = interaction(group, rownum))) +
  geom_polygon_pattern(aes(pattern = class), pattern_fill = "black",
                       pattern_angle = 45, pattern_spacing = 0.01,
                       pattern_density = 0.1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FFEFDE", "#FFBFB1", "#FF8F84", "#FF5550", "#B6EDFF", "#98D6F3", "#7CC0E1", "#5BA7CD",
                               "#D11110", "#AA0003", "#70000A", "#2B7196", "#1A5B81", "#0F4769")) +
  guides(pattern = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = "white"))) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_void()
```

Which gives:
[image]

It's close to what I want but I'm trying to figure out how to solve these issues:

1. How do I get 7 different patterns (the number of unique `class`es I have) instead of the 3 it is currently giving?
2. How do I remove the patterns from the group legend bar?
3. How do I specify the pattern line color to black for the `y_1`, `y_2`, `y_3`, `y_4` `class`es and white for the `o_1`, `o_3`, and `o_4` `class`es?

Comment: I know this is a bit off-topic, but do you really see this scatter-pie plot as illustrative of any sort of data? Looks a bit vexing to me, hardly interpretable.

Comment: Yes, I do. The pies in this example are a bit too big and probably misrepresent the real value. But even If I'd go with stacked bars instead of pies I imagine I'll run into the same issues with `ggpattern`

Comment: I agree with @GuedesBF - this is going to end up too information-dense to be easily understood.  I would seriously consider faceting by either `group` or `class` at the very least to reduce the visual complexity.

Comment: I reduced the number of pies in the example to make it clearer. I still think there's value to this as it overcomes the inherent limitations that the designated `scatterpie` package for such plots has.